# Explaining TomEE start error "You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping"

Tags: tomcat, jmx, apache-tomee

When TomEE is starting, I see this warning:

> WARNING [http-nio-80-exec-18]
> org.apache.batchee.container.services.ServicesManager.init You didn't
> specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already
> registered, skipping

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Apache BatchEE (bundled with TomEE) activates a JMX facade for JobOperator via `org.apache.batchee.jmx` (boolean). According to the official [documentation](https://geronimo.apache.org/batchee/configuration.html), the property `org.apache.batchee.jmx.application` is used to specify

> a name to distinguish job operator between applications when batchee is not shared (will be shown in JMX name)

On startup, BatchEE tries to register itself on the platform's mbean server. To do so, it relies on the app's name given via `org.apache.batchee.jmx.application`. In case this property is not set, a [default value](https://github.com/apache/geronimo-batchee/blob/5499e0635c07cde474f8dd287bbdb169987d646a/jbatch/src/main/java/org/apache/batchee/jmx/BatchEEMBean.java#L22) is used. In case, [the JMX facade is already registered with this default name](https://github.com/apache/geronimo-batchee/blob/5499e0635c07cde474f8dd287bbdb169987d646a/jbatch/src/main/java/org/apache/batchee/container/services/ServicesManager.java#L162), the log message mentioned above is printed.

If BatchEE is available in TomEE's classpath, this initalization is triggered via the `BatchEEServiceManager` during startup and the property `openejb.batchee.integration.skip` is not `true`.

If you do not need JMX monitoring on BatchEE, you can either disable the integration via `openejb.batchee.integration.skip=true` or via `org.apache.batchee.jmx=false`.